# How to make a density plot using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, density-plot

For a piecewise function

```
f(x,y) = x < 0 ? 0 : 0 <= x && x < 1 && x*y < 1 ? x : 1
```

which breaks down to following in Mathematica language

```
f(x,y) = 0 if x < 0
f(x,y) = x if 0 <= x < 1 & xy < 1
f(x,y) = 1 otherwise
```

I want to make the density plot, which should look like the following figure

[image]

How to go about it? I tried doing it like this

```
set hidden3d
set dgrid3d 50,50 qnorm 2
set view map
splot f(x,y)
```

which I know is incorrect.

**Edit:** Earlier, by mistake I wrote `xy < 1` instead of `x*y < 1` when defining piecewise function. I have corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `f(x,y)`, `xy` should read `x*y`. Check the following. Play with the sampling, i.e. `set samples` and `set isosamples` to get higher or lower resolution. Furthermore, check `help pm3d` and `help set palette`.

**Code:**

```
### plot piecewise function as a map
reset session

set size ratio 0.5
f(x,y) = x < 0 ? 0 : 0 <= x && x < 1 && x*y < 1 ? x : 1

set samples 400
set isosamples 200
set palette defined (0 '#26548a', 0.5 '#e59e4a', 1 '#fff2bf')
set view map

set xlabel "d"
set xrange [-2:2]
set xtics 1
set ylabel "b"
set yrange [0:2]

splot f(x,y) w pm3d
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]