# How to make a density plot using gnuplot for polar coordinates

Tags: gnuplot

I have a function like T(x)=0.5*(sin(sin(x))^2)^2, and i want to make a density plot in polar coordinates, using x as the angular variable.

I have tried following the steps in this question (link: [How to make a density plot using gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67223175/how-to-make-a-density-plot-using-gnuplot/67223653#67223653?newreg=27c66db423174b9ab0483967a8b8dc65) ) and i get an image like the attached one. This of course is not polar, but when I try to do it with the option "set polar", it says **"Cannot splot in polar coordinate system."**.
Is there a way of making this kind of diagram in polar coordinates?
[densityplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EioNR.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do I understand correctly, your function is only dependent on the angle, but not on the radius? Are you maybe looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/18792461/7295599